# How to identify incompatible classes in libraries?

Tags: android

#### Background

For the past few weeks, I've been on a mad quest to build a native Android client for an AWIPS2-EDEX server based on the open-source code for their Eclipse-framework-based Java client.

The specific repo of interest: https://github.com/unidata/awips2-core (and its dependencies, https://github.com/unidata/awips2-core-foss).

#### The Problem

I finally managed to get enough of awips2-core to build in Android Studio as a Gradle-based module (see my github fork at https://github.com/jskubick/awips2core-android ). After I finished celebrating my victory at getting it to build, I set out to actually make use of it in an actual Android app... then watched the build fail because awips2-core has dependencies on JAXB, which has been exhaustively documented elsewhere as being fundamentally incompatible with Android(*).

I'm now attempting to eliminate the module's dependencies on JAXB, but it got me thinking... how many MORE unexploded mines are out there waiting in the code for me to trip over... things that compile fine as "straight Java", but will blow up the moment something Android-specific references them?

**Is there any tool that can scrape through library .jar files, and identify any dependencies within them that can't be satisfied by Android?**

*Update:* my attempted project to use awips2-core directly with Android is dead. Upon further investigation, the implications of awips2-core's extensive use of Apache Camel sank in, and I realized that attempting to use awips2-core directly by Android in its present form is hopeless. As I understand it, Camel dynamically builds and compiles its own classes at runtime... which is completely impossible under Android, but allowed by "regular" Java.

This doesn't mean I've given up on my goal of writing an Android awips2-EDEX client, but it *does* look like my goal of reusing the existing code in awips2-core to write an Android client for EDEX is a lost cause & I'm going to have to write my own Android EDEX client from scratch.

---

(*) By "fundamentally incompatible", I mean that there's no known way to build it in a way that allows it to work with unmodified JAXB-using generic Java code built for Android. This is due to at least two problems:

1. Namespace problems. Think: BouncyCastle-vs-SpongyCastle. Apparently, Android hijacked SOME of JAXB's namespace for its own purposes, and Dalvik/ART's classloader won't allow you to override it with your own code using the same namespace.
2. Limits to Dalvik/ART's introspection capabilities. Basically, "real" Java has runtime introspection capabilities related to annotations that Dalvik/ART not-really-Java doesn't support... and some functionality with JAXB depends upon it.

From what I've read, various individuals over the past ~7 years have found partial work-arounds for 1 or 2, but the collective one-two punch of both has ultimately led to everyone who's tried to find a solution to either throw in the towel and write off the problem as intractable & hopeless, or hack it just enough to make it work for whatever they originally needed it for & call it a day.

Comment: "Is there any tool" -- technically, that's off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you need everything listed in https://github.com/Unidata/awips2-core-foss/tree/unidata_18.1.1/lib, I suspect that you're screwed. I would not expect many of the `javax` dependencies to work, you may need to hack a bit to get `org.apache.http` to use the Android-compatible library, Hibernate is unlikely to work well, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I hadn't even thought about Hibernate, which validates my original concerns about unearthing even MORE insatiable runtime dependencies. AFAIK, awips2-core contains libraries used by the client ("viz"), server ("edex"), both ("common"), and god-knows-what-else ("features"). I'm hoping that my present needs (an Android client capable of querying and retrieving data from an EDEX server) will only require classes from the 'common' tree, and that none of those will have javax or Hibernate dependencies (still need to check, though).

Comment: @CommonsWare (cont.) -- the really tragic thing is, I know the developers of awips2 absolutely bent over backwards to try and avoid precisely these kinds of dependencies (the spiritual predecessor of awips2, NetCDF-Java, took YEARS of refactoring by multiple developers before it could finally be used directly by Android). The fact that they happened anyway is a testament to how easy it is to accidentally introduce them if Android-compatibility isn't an explicit (and tested) goal from day one. :-(

Comment: @CommonsWare -- ugh, I think I just ran into the final and most completely-insurmountable brick wall. Unless I'm completely overlooking something obvious, or something has radically changed regarding Android since ~2012, it looks like Apache Camel is the final nail in awips2-for-android's coffin. I saw your ~7 year old comments about Camel and Android in another post, and it looks like nothing has meaningfully changed since then. As far as I can tell, awips2 uses Apache Camel EXTENSIVELY, nearly everywhere, for almost everything.

Comment: I know nothing about AWIPS2, how well its protocol is documented, etc. Hence, I have no idea how difficult a cleanroom client implementation would be. In general, getting non-Android Java code to work on Android comes down to size: the bigger the project (code + dependencies), the more likely it is that Android blockers will crop up. That's why smaller libraries either "just worked" or could be ported (e.g., Guava's `EventBus`).